# How to split a row in two, dividing a value in one column between the two while copying the values from other columns based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to duplicate every row in my dataset while at the same time dividing values from one column between the two rows but keeping the other ones constant if a condition is met. My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"),
                 class = c(2,4,6),
                 value = c(100,150,100))
```

What I want is to split now every row, dividing the `value` between those two rows and assigning two different classes to each row based on the previous class. So if `class` = 2, it is gonna be 1 and 2 after the split, and `value` divided equally between those two rows.

So it would look something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                  class = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  value = c( 50,50,75,75,50,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `bind_rows` the two, while setting the `class` of one of it to be `class - 1`, then divide the `value` by the number of observation per group, and `arrange` to desired order.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df, df %>% mutate(class = class - 1)) %>% 
  mutate(value = value/n(), .by = ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, class)

#>   ID class value
#> 1  A     1    50
#> 2  A     2    50
#> 3  B     3    75
#> 4  B     4    75
#> 5  C     5    50
#> 6  C     6    50
```